# Sorting issue in Structure Groups Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011-sp1

We experience a sorting issue in our SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 implementation. Our CM uses numbers to sort structure groups but Tridion sorts first letters and then numbers. We use Oracle 11g. What we found is that there is one environment lcmAcc that behaves the correct way. Means that it sorts first numbers and then letters. After testing and connecting different DB's (all Oracle 11g) we concluded that is not a DB issue but a setting on the Server. Whatever DB we connect with the lcmAcc (windows server) environment behaves as we want. Could it be a Tridion configuration setting that does the job or the Oracle client installed there? Can anybody give us a tip? As I see the question was asked a year ago. Quirijn did you figured it out?

Comment: to my knowledge it is a Oracle Client setting (thought actaully it could also be a server setting), but I don't know any details of it.

Comment: Check the collation sequence settings on your databases.

Comment: That's an Oracle setting right, Dom? Would NLS_Sort be on the right path?

Answer (score 4):

> Sort order on Oracle is determined by the NLS_SORT parameter on the Oracle Client. Perform the steps below to set NLS_SORT to BINARY, or choose a NLS_LANG setting that includes binary.

according to [some oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E05554_01/books/UPG_WIN/UPG_Pre-upgrade_Merge5.html)

So ensure these are the same across all installed oracle clients used to connect to Tridion databases.

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary measure you could implement a Data List Extender, take a look at the docs:

[Data Extender Example](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_E4EFBE6E5CA24C01B2531FB15AE95AE2)

All you'll have to do is re-sort the xml nodes by the Title attribute using .Net. This way you ensure you see the sorting like you want (regardless of the database) and even you can then use this mechanism to apply more rules when sorting.

Comment: Thanks but we try not to add extra complexity to the system. Implementing that will be executed in every GetList() response that happens in the system. There should be a setting that does this as one environment works as requested? I guess is something with the Oracle 11g client installation. Anybody that knows how???